# What happens to a photon leaving a grav well if it doesn't have the energy to get out of the well and the object it's leaving isn't a black hole?

Tags: gravity, visible-light, discrete

Light exists with energy E = hf.  That is supposed to be quantized and discrete but maybe "f" in the equation is continuous when not emitted specifically from an electron (moving through the g well).  But light exiting a gravity well loses energy and is red shifted.  What about light at the frequency of one in a decent gravity well?  As it tries to exit, it would lose energy, but it may get to a point when that energy is zero.  Is it reflected back into the well?  Does it kick around within the energy well that it can exist in because it can't leave?

Answer (score 4):

The situation you describe does not happen *except* in the case of black holes.

Suppose light of frequency $f_0$ is emitted at a radius $r_0$ from within a gravitational well of a spherically symmetric mass $M$, and that light is then received at some more distant radius $r_1$. Ignoring any relative motion of the emitter and receiver then the frequency of the photon at $r_1$ is given by
$$ f_1 = f_0 \left(\frac{1-r_s/r_0}{1 - r_s/r_1}\right)^{1/2}\ , $$
where $r_s = 2GM/c^2$.
Thus for any given $r_0$ then as $r_1$ increases, the received photon frequency will get smaller - it is redshifted.

However, you can see that as $r_1 \rightarrow \infty$, the redshift asymptotes to a value of $f_0\sqrt{1 - r_s/r_0}$ and so long as $r_0 > r_s$, then this is $>0$.

The only way that a photon cannot "leave" a potential well is if it is emitted from $r_0 < r_s$, in which case the photon will never be received at any $r_1>r_s$. But this *is* a black hole because $r_s$ is the "event horizon" of a Schwarzschild black hole.